# Configure rules to detect the presence of a deployment type using Powershell in SCCM

Tags: powershell, sccm, configurationmanager

I've been working for days on a Powershell script to automate the oh so tedious creating process of SCCM applications and I've run into an issue that I didn't find an answer on yet.

Heres what I have so far:

```
Import-Module $env:SMS_ADMIN_UI_PATH.Replace("\bin\i386", "\bin\configurationmanager.psd1")

$deployTypeHash = @{
        applicationName = "TestApp"
        deploymentTypeName = "TestApp"
        ContentLocation = "\\A\Network\Path"
        InstallCommand = "Install Command"
        UninstallCommand = "Uninstall Command"
        ScriptLanguage = 'PowerShell'
        InstallationBehaviorType = 'InstallForSystem'
        LogonRequirementType = 'WhetherOrNotUserLoggedOn'
        UserInteractionMode = 'Hidden'
        MaximumRuntimeMins = 120
        EstimatedRuntimeMins = 20  
        AddDetectionClause = ""
        ValueName = "UninstallString"
} 
$cla1 =  New-CMDetectionClauseRegistryKeyValue -Hive LocalMachine `
                                                      -Is64Bit `
                                                      -KeyName "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\!$($configCM.application.name)" `
                                                      -Existence  `
                                                      -PropertyType String `
                                                      -ValueName $($deployTypeHash.ValueName) 
$logical1 = $cla1.Setting.LogicalName

#COMMENT### $cla1.Connector = 'Or'


$cla2 = New-CMDetectionClauseRegistryKeyValue -Hive LocalMachine `
                                                     -Is64Bit `
                                                     -KeyName "SOFTWARE\WOW6432\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\!$($configCM.application.name)" `
                                                     -Existence  `
                                                     -PropertyType String `
                                                     -ValueName "UninstallString" 
 $logical2 = $cla1.Setting.LogicalName

 #COMMENT### $cla2.Connector = 'Or'

Add-CMScriptDeploymentType -ContentLocation $($deployTypeHash.ContentLocation) `
                               -DeploymentTypeName $($deployTypeHash.deploymentTypeName) `
                               -InstallCommand $($deployTypeHash.InstallCommand) `
                               -AddDetectionClause @($cla1, $cla2) `
                               -GroupDetectionClauses @($logical1, $logical2) `
                               -ApplicationName $($deployTypeHash.applicationName) `
                               -UninstallCommand $($deployTypeHash.UninstallCommand) `
                               -InstallationBehaviorType $($deployTypeHash.InstallationBehaviorType) `
                               -LogonRequirementType $($deployTypeHash.LogonRequirementType) `
                               -MaximumRuntimeMins $($deployTypeHash.MaximumRuntimeMins) `
                               -UserInteractionMode $($deployTypeHash.UserInteractionMode) `
                               -SlowNetworkDeploymentMode Download | Out-Null
```

I would like to be able the change the value of the logical expression used to compare registry keys in the connector of the deployment type (from 'And' to 'Or'), but none of my attempts has worked so far using this method (in comment).

Anybody knows how to accomplish this or a better way to do it maybe?

Thank you

Comment: Which version of sccm are you using? this should be possible starting with 1810 (see https://configurationmanager.uservoice.com/forums/300492-ideas/suggestions/32208376-add-cmscriptdeploymenttype-adddetectionclause-or)

Comment: Version 1902.
Thank you for the reply, I used  'Add-CM**Script**DeploymentType' not 'Add-CM**Msi**DeploymentType'.
The Add-CMScriptDeploymentType cmdlet does not seem to have the DetectionClauseConnector that Adam Meltzer is is talking about in the cmdlet's Microsoft documention..
[link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configurationmanager/add-cmscriptdeploymenttype?view=sccm-ps

Comment: I did not check it myself but the uservoice request is actually for the script deployment type so I assumed it was implemented for both and he just did not post and example for both. Note that the page for the msi type also does not mention the detectionclauseconnector parameter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configurationmanager/add-cmmsideploymenttype?view=sccm-ps) but if I check my cmdlets directly i got 3 parameter sets that support it (see also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sccm/1810-release-notes?view=sccm-ps) so it should really work

Comment: The syntax mentioned apparently does not work.. I'm getting a << Add-CMScriptDeploymentType : Cannot bind parameter 'DetectionClauseConnector'. Cannot convert the "LogicalName=$logical1;Connector="or"" value of type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable". >> error message.

Comment: I think Adam Melzer got that wrong -DetectionClauseConnector {LogicalName=$logic2;Connector="or"},{LogicalName=$logic3;Connector="or"} should probably be -DetectionClauseConnector @{LogicalName=$logic2;Connector="or"},@{LogicalName=$logic3;Connector="or"}. If it still doesn't work (I also am not sure why he would use 1 and 2 in the group but 2 and 3 in the connector) I will try it myself tomorrow I just don't have the time today. If it works I will rewrite it as a clean answer

Comment: Got it. Turns out I accidently put "$logical2 = $cla1.Setting.LogicalName" instead of "$logical2 = $cla2.Setting.LogicalName". Also, your suggestion was spot on, Adam Melzer forgot to use the '@' on both hastables. Everything works now thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Import-Module $env:SMS_ADMIN_UI_PATH.Replace("\bin\i386", "\bin\configurationmanager.psd1")

$deployTypeHash = @{
        applicationName = "TestApp"
        deploymentTypeName = "TestApp"
        ContentLocation = "\\A\Network\Path"
        InstallCommand = "Install Command"
        UninstallCommand = "Uninstall Command"
        ScriptLanguage = 'PowerShell'
        InstallationBehaviorType = 'InstallForSystem'
        LogonRequirementType = 'WhetherOrNotUserLoggedOn'
        UserInteractionMode = 'Hidden'
        MaximumRuntimeMins = 120
        EstimatedRuntimeMins = 20  
        AddDetectionClause = ""
        ValueName = "UninstallString"
} 
$cla1 =  New-CMDetectionClauseRegistryKeyValue -Hive LocalMachine `
                                                      -Is64Bit `
                                                      -KeyName "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\!$($configCM.application.name)" `
                                                      -Existence  `
                                                      -PropertyType String `
                                                      -ValueName $($deployTypeHash.ValueName) 
$logical1 = $cla1.Setting.LogicalName


$cla2 = New-CMDetectionClauseRegistryKeyValue -Hive LocalMachine `
                                                     -Is64Bit `
                                                     -KeyName "SOFTWARE\WOW6432\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\!$($configCM.application.name)" `
                                                     -Existence  `
                                                     -PropertyType String `
                                                     -ValueName "UninstallString" 
$logical2 = $cla2.Setting.LogicalName


Add-CMScriptDeploymentType -ContentLocation $($deployTypeHash.ContentLocation) `
                               -DeploymentTypeName $($deployTypeHash.deploymentTypeName) `
                               -InstallCommand $($deployTypeHash.InstallCommand) `
                               -AddDetectionClause @($cla1, $cla2) `
                               -GroupDetectionClauses @($logical1, $logical2) `
                               -ApplicationName $($deployTypeHash.applicationName) `
                               -UninstallCommand $($deployTypeHash.UninstallCommand) `
                               -InstallationBehaviorType $($deployTypeHash.InstallationBehaviorType) `
                               -LogonRequirementType $($deployTypeHash.LogonRequirementType) `
                               -MaximumRuntimeMins $($deployTypeHash.MaximumRuntimeMins) `
                               -UserInteractionMode $($deployTypeHash.UserInteractionMode) `
                               -DetectionClauseConnector @(@{LogicalName=$logical1;Connector="or"},@{LogicalName=$logical2;Connector="or"}) `
                               -SlowNetworkDeploymentMode Download | Out-Null
```